# XML change value where attribute is

Tags: php, xml, attributes

With PHP I want to change the value in the node where attribute is something I specify.
The XML file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<days>
<Maandag id="1">0</Maandag>
<Dinsdag  id="2">0</Dinsdag>
<Woensdag id="3">0</Woensdag>
<Donderdag  id="4">0</Donderdag>
<Vrijdag  id="5">0</Vrijdag>
<Zaterdag  id="6">0</Zaterdag>
<Zonday  id="0">0</Zonday> 
</days>
```

For example:
Today is Monday so jddayofweek(0) = 1
Then the value of the node with id=1 needs to change, so in the end we get:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<days>
<Maandag id="1">3</Maandag>
<Dinsdag  id="2">0</Dinsdag>
<Woensdag id="3">0</Woensdag>
<Donderdag  id="4">0</Donderdag>
<Vrijdag  id="5">0</Vrijdag>
<Zaterdag  id="6">0</Zaterdag>
<Zonday  id="0">0</Zonday> 
</days>
```

How do I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend `simpleXML`, because it is - well - *simple*:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$id = 1; 

$day = $xml->xpath("*[@id=`$id`]")[0];
$day[0] = 5;
```

see the result:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

**Comments:**

- the `xpath`-expression will select the day by `$id` and give back an array of `SimpleXML`-elements.
- select the 1st element (index `[0]`) and store it in `$day` (requires PHP >= 5.4)

see it working: https://eval.in/388827

**Thinking further**

If you make that XML, add clarity and flexibility by making it like this:

```
<days>
    <day name="Maandag" id="1">0</day>
    <day name="Dinsdag" id="2">0</day>
    <etc />
</days>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change it using `DOMdocument` and `DOMpath` Just change the xml filename, `data.xml` (2x). Set `$select` and `$changeTo`.

```
<?php 

//Set your variables
$select = 1; //id you'd like to change
$changeTo = 3; //value you would like to change to

//Creating a new DOMDocument
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

//from file
$xmlDoc->load("data.xml");

//Creating a new DOMPath
$Xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

//the query selects all Matches any element node (*) that have a "id" attribute with a value of $select
$results = $Xpath->query('*[@id=' . $select . ']');

//Change node
$results->item(0)->nodeValue = $changeTo;

//Save document
$xmlDoc->save("data.xml");

echo "Edited document saved!"

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your files are always small and similar content (like your example) you could preg_replace() them (or maybe str_replace())...the best solution is to write your own XML parser, which is a good rite-of-passage for all programmers.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php